# Shopify outputs multiple tags when looping

Tags: loops, shopify

I have a product with about 10 tags and I'm trying to check if a product tag equals 'OurPrice' and if it does display Our Price otherwise display Sale. Im using this code:

```
{% for tag in product.tags %}
 {% if tag == 'OurPrice' %}Our Price:
 {% else %}Sale:
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm only wanting it to display one or the other, currently i'm getting Sale:Sale:Sale:Sale:Sale:Sale:Sale:Sale:Sale:Sale:Sale:Our Price:Sale:

Is there a way to fall check for this?

EDIT: I now have:

```
{% assign isOurPrice = False  %}
{% for tag in product.tags  %}
 {% if tag == 'OurPrice' %}Our Price:{% assign isOurPrice = True  %}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if isOurPrice == False %}Sale:
{% endif %}
```

which displays Our Price: Sale: which is displaying Sale when it shouldn't. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out shopify offer code for this - 'contains'

```
{% if product.tags contains "OurPrice" %}
  Our Price:
{% else %}
  Sale:
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% $isOurPrice = False;  %}
{% for tag in product.tags  %}
 {% if tag == 'OurPrice' %}Our Price:
 {% $isOurPrice = True; %}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if $isOurPrice == False %}Sale:
{% endif %}
```

Very easily you can remove the 'Sale:' from the `{ else`}. To output if it's a sales price only.

Comment: i tried this, better but im still getting Our Price: Sale: any idea why?

Comment: @Alex.. cDima has not mentioned the line to flip `$isOurPrice` to `true`.

Comment: @AlexMurray - fixed a line, please try again